# Is it possible to hide a binary file from the system

Tags: linux, centos7, openssl, make

A VPS on Centos 7 came with a very old version of openssl. I built and installed a newer version of openssl. (details below) This newer openssl was only installed in order to upgrade to a much newer version of curl. It was intended to call this curl specifically by location and not to integrate it into any other programs.

Apparently, the installation caused an issue for exim (and who knows what else). Now, updating exim is failing due to not finding libssl.so.1.1.

Can the openssl binary in `/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl` be ***hidden*** from the system? (so that exim will update) I'm not quite sure what is happening in the exim build, but of course it worked before.

I suppose two solutions are to move the openssl install to /opt or to rename the openssl to something else. However, I'd like to learn if there is a simpler solution.

All ideas welcome. Thanks for considering this.

Some system info:

```
[root@vps ~]# which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

[root@vps ~]# whereis openssl
openssl: /usr/bin/openssl /usr/lib64/openssl /usr/include/openssl /usr/local/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1

[root@vps ~]# /usr/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

[root@vps ~]# /usr/lib64/openssl version
-bash: /usr/lib64/openssl: Is a directory

[root@vps ~]# /usr/include/openssl version
-bash: /usr/include/openssl: Is a directory

[root@vps ~]# /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023
```

```
---
*** Could not run ./exim -bV -C /dev/null to find version number ***
*** Exim installation failed ***
./exim: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
Moving exim binary.
---
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you showed nothing to really display that some "binary file is hidden".

Exim is likely expecting to find the library not in /usr/local/lib(64) but in /usr/lib(64) or /lib(64). Check your `/etc/ld.so.conf` for details. You can direct you application to prefer some path, using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, e.g. run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path exim` to define this variable for just one command. This is the way one might run ancient programs on newer systems (for one case I need to use old OpenSSL and old build of a specific program, but I don't want to have old OpenSSL system-wide, so I put enough old libraries for that program into custom directory and start it like this).

Also, notice the soname: if you built newer OpenSSL, you had to **rebuild all the dependent software**; different soname means ABI is likely changed. New OpenSSL creates `libssl3.so` and doesn't create `libssl.so.1.1` which your build of an application expects. In some cases you may symlink one to another, but problems are likely; rebuild is necessary to resolve such issues. (This is why long-term support distros are so hard to maintain: one needs to backport all fixes into older versions of applications and libraries to not change ABIs and sonames so you can just upgrade the library package version without creating other problems for dependent applications.)

Lastly, when working with production servers, never use `make` and `make install`, it'll turn your system into mess you'll never be able to clean. Build your own packages out from SRPMs (or DEB-SRCs, if we talk about Debian-based systems) and install them using package manager.

Comment: `cat /etc/ld.so.conf` reports 3 lines in response `include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib64`

Comment: Nice explanation. The binary is not hidden, I wanted to hide it. Your 2nd paragraph explained the situation.  I will have to "hide" the newer openssl. After deleting /usr/local/openssl the exim update was successfully installed.

Comment: "Build your own packages ..." == "so much to learn".  I am a web developer, not a system admin. :)

Comment: First of all, this is not so much to learn. If you're developer, you shouldn't bother with system administration, but then you should learn how to distribute your software in a way that can be handled by administrators — release RPMs or container images or whatever is applicable for your case. And, speak your requirements: if you need modern curl and OpenSSL, *require* that, and then running on CentOS 7 will be not an option; your users will be either forced to not use your software or use newer OS. Or, if there was a requirement given to run on CentOS 7, *you* can't depend on newer software.

Answer (score 0):

When you pick a stable distro such as CentOS, part of the deal is that things won't break. Sure, you won't get new features, but RedHat/CentOS will back port security fixes and bug fixes to old versions of the software, so that you will see minimal changes.

You don't get a new curl. To get that, you have to update to a newer release; CentOS 7 is stuck with the version it shipped with.

Furthermore, both curl and openssl is *essential* system libraries, used by a *lot* of other software. When you start mucking with those, things break. Don't.

Upgrade to a newer distro release. If you want new shiny toys look at a distro with a more frequent release cycle.

Comment: I appreciate your point about stability. You didn't really answer the question. Isn't the other side of the coin that additional software can be safely installed on Linux?  The intention is to intelligently compliment and improve the server so that it compliments my purposes.

Comment: Yes, I answered the question; if you need newer software you should not run old CentOS releases. What you ask is possible, but quickly entails rebuilding a lot of pieces, because they all depend on openssl. You could of course play with different paths - which can make sense on a developer workstation, but *not* on a server. The two answers you have are more or less to this effect.

Comment: I don't have much choice in OS releases. Alma Linux 8 only runs curl 7.61. (Alma Linux 9 - 7.76) After migrating to newer bistro, similar issues will arise.

Comment: Why does "different paths" not make sense on a server?

Comment: Because this is way to a DLL hell, and this is exactly what the stable (LTS) server distro was meant to avoid. It makes no sense to use such a distro *and* depend on "bleeding edge" software, you have to choose one. Serously, use Ubuntu, which you will be required to upgrade more often, which implies you'd have much newer software. Or, split your workload and use Docker: containers ship all the libraries, so you can have a CentOS 7-based container for one workload and Debian 12 for other and something else for third; *this* is how different paths are properly implemented in production.

Comment: @DavidC In addition to what Nikita mentions, security patching quickly becomes *very* messy in such scenarios. You will manually have to keep track of changes, which is *hard* work. I struggle enough with following updates in Debian repositories, never mind going straight to the source.